# Why does my taxonomy code display the first alphabetical term?

Tags: taxonomy

What i am trying to do is echo the last hierarchial child term for the taxonomy. My taxonomy is `propertytype`.

My hierarchial structure is:

- Real Estate (Parent)
- Commercial (Child)
- Offices (Child of Commercial)
- Basement (Child of Commercial)

So  in the above case i would only like to echo `Offices`, or which ever the last hierarchial child term is.

I thought my code below would do this, but it actually echoes `Commercial` because `Commercial` is alphabetically before Offices.  Now `Basement` will be ok because it is alphabetically before `Commercial`.

How do I always echo the last hierarchial child term only?

My code is:

```
$terms = get_the_terms($wp_query->post->ID, 'propertytype');                    
//die(print_r($terms));
$props = array();
foreach ($terms as $term) { 
    $hasChildrenTest = get_term_children($term->ID, 'propertytype' );
    if ($term->parent) {
        if (empty($hasChildrenTest) && !is_wp_error($hasChildrenTest)) {
            $props[] = $term->slug;
        }
    }
}
echo $props[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

With [wp_get_object_terms()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms) you're able to manipulate the sorting.

Make sure you tweak the sorting to what you want.

**Try something more or less like this (*Updated: 5/17/2012 -- 8:15AM*):**

```
$taxonomyName = 'producttype';
$terms = wp_get_object_terms($wp_query->post->ID, $taxonomyName, array('orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC', 'fields' => 'all'));
if(!empty($terms)){
    if(!is_wp_error($terms)){
        for($i = 0; $i < count($terms); $i++){
            if($terms[$i]->parent != 0){
                $termChildren[] = $terms[$i];
            }
        }
    }
}
print_r($termChildren);
```

### Output a list of all public custom taxonomies

```
<?php 
$args=array(
  'public'   => true,
  '_builtin' => false

); 
$output = 'names'; // or objects
$operator = 'and'; // 'and' or 'or'
$taxonomies=get_taxonomies($args,$output,$operator); 
if  ($taxonomies) {
  foreach ($taxonomies  as $taxonomy ) {
    echo '<p>'. $taxonomy. '</p>';
  }
}
?>
```

### Output a list of all public custom post types

```
<?php 
$args=array(
  'public'   => true,
  '_builtin' => false
); 
$output = 'names'; // names or objects, note names is the default
$operator = 'and'; // 'and' or 'or'
$post_types=get_post_types($args,$output,$operator); 
  foreach ($post_types  as $post_type ) {
    echo '<p>'. $post_type. '</p>';
  }
?>
```

Comment: Hi There, Thanks for the response.  Unfortunately i get the same results with this as i do with my code where is does not seperate the child and child of a child.  Just in case I am missing something, can i display a child of a child?  the above code seems to exclude the parent (which is correct) but then echos the first alphabetical child term associated with the post.  So in my above example, because COMMERCIAL is already a child, and OFFICES is a child of COMMERCIAL, it displays COMMERCAL.  No matter what i try, I can't echo just OFFICES : ( Any ideas?  Thanks in advance

Comment: get_term_by()
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by

get_term_children()
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_children

Comment: @PaulB made some revisions. Try this.

Comment: hi michael, tried the code but it gives a php error : (

Comment: @PaulB replace where it says 1029 with `$wp_query->post->ID`, i updated the code again

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks for the responding again.  I replaced taxonomy name to 'propertytype' but it does not display anything (i.e does not ech any term)?  I get no PHP error now though. I am using a custom post type, not sure if that makes a difference?

Comment: @PaulB I have updated my answer again. This please run the two code blocks for displaying all of your registered taxonomies and registered custom post types. Update your question with the list of each. Also, please paste the full .php file, or the BLOCK of code you are currently using on your website. **If your code is inside a loop, include the surrounding loop as well.**